# EXASOL Explain Analyse Query

Tags: sql, sql-execution-plan, exasolution

I want to get the query plan in Exasol database to check the total execution time, memory and cpu usage. Profiling in Exasol is so complex and difficult to understand.

1. Is there any way to get the query plan like `explain analyze` in PostgreSQL or any other simple way?
2. Please explain how to read the query plan in Exasol without executing the query?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the [EXASOL User Manual](https://www.exasol.com/support/secure/attachment/28846/EXASolution_User_Manual-5.0.0-en.pdf) about profiling a query. I agree it's a bit cumbersome :)

Or you can use the scripts I wrote to have an `explain` like command: [exasol-explain](https://github.com/francescomucio/exasol-explain)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be useful for someone who will try to use EXASOL Explain. There is a script with one missed field in select statement in exasol-explain/scripts/sqlprofile.lua, after temp_db_ram_peak field should follow:

> max(PERSISTENT_DB_RAM_PEAK) as PERSISTENT_DB_RAM_PEAK

Otherwise "explain" and "explain_this" return an error "incorrect numbers of result column"